# What is the thing behind the question mark doing?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

What is the thing behind the question mark doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is

> (ahem) LAYING

because the other pictures are

> [Max Roach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Roach) DRUMMING

> [Sidney Bechet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Bechet) PIPING

> [Jonathon Edwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Edwards_(triple_jumper)) LEAPING

> [The Nicholas Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_Brothers) DANCING

> [Vermeer's milkmaid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Milkmaid_(Vermeer)) MILKING

> [Michael Phelps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Phelps) SWIMMING

Ergo the next picture will be

> something LAYING per the [Twelve Days of Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song))